# Maven dependencies in IntelliJ project

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have an intelliJ project in Java that's using Maven/Spring/SpringBoot for my internship and I just cloned the repo from AzureDevOps and was having some errors for my dependencies , which can be seen on the bottom right of the photo for the "service-integration" directory/module.

I'm new to Maven and was wondering if someone could explain what's going on and how I can remedy the situation. After cloning the repo I ran did run "mvn clean install" and the BUILD was SUCCESSFUL and I did load the pom.xml files to create the modules for the root directories but I am still getting dependencies errors (red squigly lines) for the service-integration.

Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does Build -> Rebuild Project action end successfully? Does re-opening project help? Also verify the Maven settings (**JDK for importer** and **Maven home directory**) in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven and Maven | Importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to build your project in IntelliJ, **Build -> Rebuild Project**. If that does not help, try **File -> Invalidate cache/ restart..**

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to Maven and just bought a Udemy course on it. Hillariously enough restarting IntelliJ actually fixed it :/ though I have no idea why lol, thanks again

Answer (score 2):

This is nasty. In some companies people just get used to it. :-(

There are many things you can try:

- Reimport Maven project (first button in Maven window)
- Build -> Rebuild Project
- File -> Invalidate cache
- restart Idea
- check if you have proxy correctly configured & intellij idea & maven use it
- update to newer Maven version
- delete .idea directory and recreate project from pom.xml
- delete .m2/repository directory and let Idea download everything
- more tips: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207369215-Maven-Dependencies-Red-underlines

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to Maven and just bought a Udemy course on it. Hillariously enough restarting IntelliJ actually fixed it :/ though I have no idea why lol, thanks again